# SerializationException on junit test

Tags: java, apache, serialization, junit

I have the following classes:

```
import lombok.Data;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private String age;
}
```

---

Main Application

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person v = new Person() {{
            setAge("SD");
        }};
        Person person2 = SerializationUtils.clone(v);
    }
}
```

---

Test Class

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Person v = new Person() {{
            setAge("SD");
        }};
        Person person2 = SerializationUtils.clone(v);
    }
}
```

In the main application the serialization works and in the unit test it doesn't.
It throws SerializationException with the following details:
org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationException: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mypackage.TestClass

I'm using intellij and the project is maven project and the tests are JUnit4. dependency version:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Please advise how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring an anonymous class in the test.

Anonymous classes in non-static scopes (in an instance method, constructor, instance initializer, or instance member initializer) implicitly enclose a reference to the enclosing class (in this case, `TestClass`).

As that class isn't serializable, it can't be serialized.

Declare your anonymous subclass as a static class instead.

```
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Person v = new TestPerson();
        Person person2 = SerializationUtils.clone(v);
    }

  static class TestPerson extends Person {
    {
      setAge("SD");
    }
  }
}
```

Or, better, don't use [double-brace initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1958636/3788176), especially if you don't understand the problems it causes with respect to serialization (as well as other problems):

```
Person v = new Person();
v.setAge("SD");
Person person2 = SerializationUtils.clone(v);
```

Comment: What is the anonymous class i declared in the test?

Comment: @DanielGrin "`new Person() {{ ... }}`".

Comment: Can you please add an example for both ways?

Comment: @DanielGrin "both ways"?

Comment: Thanks alot it solved my problem but still one question. im using the same anonymous  class in the MainApp why is it working there?

Comment: @DanielGrin because either you are declaring it in a static scope, or in instance scope in a class which implements `Serializable`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182328/discussion-between-daniel-grin-and-andy-turner).